# create dummy variables while aggregating in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate, dummy-variable

I want create to dummy variables while aggregating a dataframe in R.

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection('ID Score Info
1     1     A    1
2     1     A    10
3     1     B    7
4     2     C    8
5     2     B    9
6     2     B    1
7     3     B    7
8     3     C    8
9     3     C    3
10     3     A    2'))
```

Basically, I want to aggregate by "ID" and count no of rows with same ID which is easy but I also need to create dummy variables based on the column "Row". If A/B/C is present within the same ID, the dummy variables will have value of 1, 0 otherwise.
For example, There is no A for ID no 2 therefore Score_A for ID no 2 is 0 but 1 for Score_B and Score_C.

Output would be as follows:

```
      ID  Count Score_A Score_B Score_C
1     1     3      1      1       0
2     2     3      0      1       1
3     3     4      1      1       1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Score_C should be for 0 for ID 1

Comment: You were right! fixed it.

Comment: `cbind(aggregate(Info ~ ID, dat, length), +!!table(dat$ID, dat$Score))`

Comment: this is a great alternative using base functions @rawr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a frequency column 'Count' after grouping by 'ID', then add the second grouping with 'Score', `summarise` with the first value of 'Count' and a column of 1, and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
dat %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Count = n()) %>%
    group_by(Score = paste0("Score_", Score), add = TRUE) %>%
    summarise(Count = first(Count), n1 = 1)  %>%
    spread(Score, n1, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups: ID [3]
#     ID Count Score_A Score_B Score_C
#* <int> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1     3    1.00    1.00    0   
#2     2     3    0       1.00    1.00
#3     3     4    1.00    1.00    1.00
```

Comment: wow....so many things can be done with the "dplyr" package. thanks so much @akrun for your quick help!!